# Attempting to draw circle with Raphael, works when non-dynamic, does not work when dynamic

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael

I am trying to draw a circle after a few calculations are performed over top of a td. When I ran the the following code, it works:

```
$('#priority_one').width($('#learning_streams').width());
$('#priority_one').height($('#learning_streams').height());
var priority_one_paper = new Raphael('priority_one', $('#priority_one').width(), $('#priority_one').height());
var priority_one_circle = priority_one_paper.circle((pos.left).toFixed(0), (pos.top).toFixed(0), (width/2).toFixed(0));
priority_one_circle.attr('stroke','#000000');
```

But when I try to make it dynamic (the td changes depending on the input by the user) it no longer works. Code:

```
function circlePriorityOne() {
    //priority_one is a div absolutely positioned over a table called learning_streams
    //sets size of priority_one based off the table learning_streams
    $('#priority_one').width($('#learning_streams').width());
    $('#priority_one').height($('#learning_streams').height());


    //creates the 'paper' to draw the circle on
    var priority_one_paper = new Raphael('priority_one', $('#priority_one').width(), $('#priority_one').height());

    var main = getMax(priority_one_count); //returns the id of the td to circle
    var pos = $('#'+main).position();
    var width = $('#'+main).width();

    //using toFixed() to get rid of decimals
    var priority_one_circle = priority_one_paper.circle((pos.left).toFixed(0), (pos.top).toFixed(0), (width/2).toFixed(0));
    priority_one_circle.attr('stroke','#000000');
}
```

See anything wrong with this? Thanks.

Comment: "Does not work"... Does not cook a meal? Does drive your car? Does not say "Hello"? :D What is it doing? Any errors in the console? Did you check the variables (main, pos, width, ...)?

Comment: There are no errors coming up. It is supposed to draw a circle. It does not. I believe the position of the td is being captured relative to the document, not the table. That will throw off the position of the circle. I am changing it over to grab the position relative to a div tag wrapped around the table. I will see if that changes anything.

Comment: Forgot to answer the rest of your question. main, pos, and width all come up with the expected values.

Comment: For the sake of both readability, and performance, try not to duplicate calls to jQuery.  For example, `$('#priority_one')` is used in several locations.  Save it to a variable in your function, and use the variable, rather than having jQuery search the DOM each time you call it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right. [.position()](http://api.jquery.com/position/) gets the current position relative to a parent element.

You should use [.offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) instead, which gets the current position relative to the `document`

**Edit**
I'm not quite sure, because I haven't tested it but it should do what you want^^

```
var td = $("#td"),
    pos_td = td.offset(),
    table = td.parents("table"),
    pos_table = table.offset();

// td's position relative to table
console.log("left: " + (pos_td.left - pos_table.left));
console.log("top: " + (pos_td.top - pos_td.top));
```

Comment: I would like to get the position relative to the parent element (table in this case). .position() was giving me the position relative to the document for some reason. Does it not treat a td element as a child of table?

Comment: Changed the table over to position: absolute. Now it works. :P Thanks for your help Andreas. I will set this to the answer as you got me thinking in the right direction.